# How can I save API response body or property in an environment variable or json to use it later in other requests in Cypress

Tags: api, testing, cypress, e2e-testing

API runs locally(and in future in a circleCI container) so I don't need to stub responses, only real requests and real responses.

When I send a POST request, it creates an event and returns a big response body containing a unique ID.
I need to store that unique ID somewhere(as env variable, json or worst case scenario a const) so that I can access and use it in UPDATE request later and in the end in DELETE request to delete that Event from the system.

Is there a way to do this?

There is a way to retrieve that ID from the DB, but I really don't want to do it that way

Comment: Is this about in-browser JavaScript? For that you can use a cookie, or localStorage. Please clarify your question.

Comment: hey Chris, sorry for posting unclear question. It is a question regarding Cypress it uses JS but I just deleted that tag to clear confusion who hasn't used Cypress. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the unique ID in the fixture file and then later update or read from it:

```
cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/someurl',
}).then((resp) => {

    // Expect success response
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
  
    //Write Unique ID to a fixture file
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testdata.json', {
        "id": resp.uniqueID
    })
})
```

If you want to update the value of the Unique ID, you can do something like this:

```
cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/testdata.json", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err);
    };
}).then((data) => {
    data.id = newUniqueID //save the New Value of Unique ID
    cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/testdata.json", JSON.stringify(data)) //Write it to the fixtures file
})
```

Comment: Wow, this solution is gold, thank you very much. I was thinking the only solution will be with using promises(which is hell), but this changes everything. Thanks